# JAVA LinkedList issue

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having trouble with java.util.LinkedList. I am getting a null pointer exception upon using the poll() on the list even after adding an element to the list. I am not using threads or anything similar to threads.
 
Any help is appreciated. Below is the myMethod code which is called from a main method of another class:

```
  void myMethod(Node start, int startRow){
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    LinkedList<Integer> rowQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    queue.addFirst(start);
    rowQueue.addFirst((Integer)startRow);
    System.out.println( rowQueue.size() );      

    while (queue.size()!=0){            
        Node n = queue.poll();
        int row = rowQueue.poll().intValue(); //This is the line 33 in the error!
            /*Some remaining code which uses variables n and row. The thread of control does not reach here */

    }
  }
```

Below is the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BFS.isConnected(LinkedListTest.java:33)
    at GraphsMain.main(GraphsMain.java:36)
1
ZERO
```

I am confused because the print statements execute after the error, and clearly I have written them the other way around. Is this a threading issue at all? I know that LinkedLists are not synchronized, but is that the problem here? should I be worried about it just for a simple implementation?

Comment: `System.err` and `System.out` are two separate streams.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks. So its not a threading issue then. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing particularly, just `stderr` is just unbuffered here while `stdout` is, so it appears to you as output before hand. If you set `System.err` to `System.out`, you'll see the output you're expecting (e.g. `System.setErr(System.out);`).

Comment: @rgamber: Consider posting your **actual** code and not editing your question every time. This makes all our answer look wrong :) Besides the one that you've right now wont event print 1 and ZERO like you've set it up.

Comment: @Sujay I had just posted the code which was relevant to the error. I have updated it to the actual code.

Comment: @oldrinb I did not lie about my code. The gist of the question is that if I am adding an element to the List, I should not get a null pointer when I try to retrieve that element.

Comment: @oldrinb Words like 'lying' are entirely out of place in a technical discussion. The word you should have used is 'mistaken'.

Comment: @EJP maybe, but I didn't think mistaken quite fits the insistence that this code shows us the entire picture despite letting him know it doesn't.

Comment: @oldrinb I'm speaking about what you said, not what you think. I don't know what you think, any more than you know whether he is lying or not. You do know that he's mistaken, and that's what you should have said.

Comment: @EJP I (and every person ever, for that matter) arguably know nothing... I can only post, speak, write, and generally communicate what I *think* ;-) I understand your point, but it's not like lying excludes being mistaken... I just meant that I believe his statements to be incorrect.

Comment: @oldrinb Most of that is just waffle frankly, but you are expected to stay within the generally accepted bounds for a technical discussion, and you didn't. The idea is to talk about facts and statements rather than about people.

Comment: @EJP apologies, I see your point now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that you've some elements to your *queue* and nothing in your *rowQueue*. Then your logic in the while loop would work as follows:

- `Node n = queue.poll();` will get the first and *only* element from the queue and store in the n variable.
- It would check if the size of *rowQueue* is zero or not. If it is, it would print a zero
- However, *and your problem lies in here*, it would still try to `poll()` again, get a null this time and call `intValue()` on the returned value, resulting in the NullPointerException

The issue as such lies with the following logic in your code:

```
        if(rowQueue.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("ZERO");
        }
        int row = rowQueue.poll().intValue();
```

While you're checking if `rowQueue.size()` is 0, and if true, you should not only print *Zero* but also ensure that you do not perform `int row = rowQueue.poll().intValue();`. So you should consider breaking out of the loop or something along those lines.

So you should try something like this:

```
        if(rowQueue.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("ZERO");
            break; //This ensures that you come out of the loop
        }
        int row = rowQueue.poll().intValue();
```

Comment: I had added the if loop with the print statement after I am got the error. I am confused because I am adding one element before I call the poll() on the list.

Comment: @Sujay there are 2 entirely separate queues.

Comment: @oldrinb: Woops, didn't see that. Updated my answer....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`LinkedList<E>.poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll%28%29) returns either the object in the linked list, or null if the list is empty.  It's very much the case that your list is empty when you try to retrieve the integer value from it, as you don't place that call inside of a check for the list's size.

Answer (score 1):

All you are missing is an `else` statement, The reason you are getting a `NullPointerException` is because there is `ZERO` items in `rowQueue` (referenced on line 33).

[image: zero out]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/bnphs3ty.dvk.png))</sub>

```
    int row; //declare and (optional : initialize it to something)
    //only poll the linkedlist if there is something in it...
    if(rowQueue.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("ZERO");
    } else {
     row = rowQueue.poll().intValue();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. I didn't have the if loop in the first place. My confusion is because I call the addFirst() method on the list before I call the poll(). So I should not get a null pointer right? (I have edited the question to remove the if loop - sorry about that.)

Comment: Yes but you are only adding to the `queue` linkedlist with `queue.addFirst(start);`, you have excluded the `addFirst` call on the `rowQueue` linkedlist (remember they are both separate lists).

Comment: @Killrawr 5th line of his snippet: `rowQueue.addFirst((Integer)startRow);`

Comment: @oldrinb right you are, thanks!

Comment: @Killrawr I do have rowQueue.addFirst((Integer)startRow); after the line queue.addFirst(start);